# jQuery power to handle loops or recursion

Tags: jquery

I have a large amount of Data, which has to be arranged in the form of Tree with checkboxes at the client side.

I am planning to use jQuery to make a tree for me like jstree. The question is that, will the jQuery be able to handle data in forms of 1,00,000 rows?

Comment: I think it can handle but the loading time of your page will be increased

Comment: Will the browser crash? or will the loading time will be in magnitude of minutes?

Comment: This has less to do with Jquery and more to do with the client and how much memory they have. That said, why in God's name would you send 1,000,000 rows of data at once to anyone??

Comment: i do not see why browser will crush I mean i have not used jstree but i have used jquery for stuff like this and if everything right it should not crush but loading of page increases

Comment: The server site is in magento, doing it using server side coding takes 5 minutes to complete. I have a menu which appears in the form of tree. https://test.tomofo.com/magento/index.php/ [the Region and Activities]

Comment: So are you saying the excuse for not delivering a smaller, more reasonable amount of data to the user is because it's easier for you not to do that?  You need to remember that your site should be easy for the user to use, not for you to make.

Comment: @thescientist exactly thats what i intend. I dont know how to do make it right, thats why the question in Stackoverflow. I have tried using AJAX and wish to explore other possibilities.

Comment: people have already provided good suggestions.  Only deliver some of the data, and then load more in response to user events.  like clicking on a more data link, scrolling, etc.  Maybe if you showed some code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rather doubt that a design with 1,000,000 of anything in a single web page is the best way to build a web page.  It's going to take a lot of memory.  It's going to take a while to load and parse and there's no reason to ever display that many of anything all at once.  You really need to rethink the usability of such a large dataset so users can specify a small set of data (probably less than a few hundred items) that they are interested in and willing to scroll through to find the ones they want.

A more performant solution would start out with large sections of your tree collapsed and would load things (using ajax) upon demand as the viewer asks to view more of the data.  Searches of the entire data set would be done on a server with the benefit of a real database.

Comment: The server site is in magento, doing it using server side coding takes 5 minutes to complete. I have a menu which appears in the form of tree. test.tomofo.com/magento/index.php [the Region and Activities]. Its being loaded using AJAX right now.

Comment: @user1147634 - I'm not sure why you think client-side coding is going to be faster than server-side coding - particularly when you first have to download all the data to the client before you can do anything.  A 5 minute operation on the server is a poorly design operation.  Either the data isn't stored or organized appropriately or you need to prepare the data ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a pretty large form (1,000,000 elements).  Is there possibly another implementation that would get you what you need with a smaller amount of data on the client and form?

Comment: The server site is in magento, doing it using server side coding takes 5 minutes to complete. I have a menu which appears in the form of tree. test.tomofo.com/magento/index.php [the Region and Activities]